# print contents of remaining tags after a tag beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i just printed all the contents of **li** using `.find_all('li')` and i want to continue printing **'p'** tags after **li** tag ends, like not **'p'** tags in the beginning of html or inbetween. 'p' tags or remaining tags at the end. please help. Basically need everything after final list-end tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<html>
<p>
don't need this
</p>
<li>
text i need
</li>
<li>
<p>
don't need this
</p>
<p>
don't need this
</p>
<li>
text i need 
    <ol>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>
text i need
</li>
<p>
also need this
</p>
<p>
and this
</p>
<p>
and this too
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for li in soup.select("li"):
    if li.find_parent("li"):
        continue
    print(" ".join(li.text.split()))
    print("--sep--")
```

**this prints**

```
text i need
--sep--
text i need text i need but appended to parent li tag text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need
--sep--
```

thanks to @Andrej Kesely

**i need this**

```
text i need
--sep--
text i need text i need but appended to parent li tag text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need
--sep--
also need this
--sep--
and this
--sep--
and this too
--sep--
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
for li in soup.select("li:not(li li)"): 
    print(" ".join([
        d.get_text().strip() for d in li.descendants 
        if 'NavigableString' in str(type(d)) and 
        d.parent.name == 'li' and d.get_text().strip()
    ])) 
    print("--sep--")

# for the p tags after ANY of the [outermost] li tags
for p in soup.select("li:not(li li) ~ p"):  print(p.text.strip(), "\n--sep--")
```

(Using `:not(li li)` lets you not need the `if li.find_parent("li"): continue` part.)

This should get you

- the text from [outermost] `li` tags, but only made up of strings that are **directly** inside that `li` tag or an `li` tag inside it

and then

- text from `p` tags that are [sibling to a preceding](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/#general-sibling-combinator) outermost `li` tag. (If you want only `p` tags after the *last* `li`, use `for p in soup.select("li:not(li li) ~ p:not(:has(~ li))")...`)

Comment: do i need to change the parser or something? this prints only

--sep--

--sep--

--sep--

Comment: @AjaySuryaSenthilrajan maybe try `html5lib` parser? [I actually didn't pass any parser argument at all when testing (sorry I forgot to mention that), but even just installing html5lib made a difference to the results I used to get from soupsieve]